# Can I change directory to a Windows drive in Ubuntu Bash on WSL?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a super newbie for Ubuntu and basically need Ubuntu for a Python package. 
I would like to run a Python file in say `e:/username/folder1/folder2/python.py`. I tried every method online and the only reply is `bash: cd./e: No such file or directory`. I am not sure whether it is because of the bash windows or virtualenv.

When I use bash on Ubuntu on Windows, `ls`, it says `VIRTUALENV_DIR`. `cd`, it says `/home/username`. The `cd ..` etc changes the directory a little, but not another drive, nor the folder I would like it to find.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

WSL stores your Windows drives in the `/mnt` folder, with the name of the drive as a subfolder. For example your `C:\` drive will be present at `/mnt/c/` for you to use.

Keeping this in mind, you can swap to your specific folder like so:

```
cd /mnt/e/username/folder1/folder2
```

Comment: Sure you want to `cd` to a file? looks like `cd /mnt/e/username/folder1/folder2/` makes more sense

Comment: @dufte Good catch. Yay for copy-paste!

Comment: for ubuntu 16.04, it is inside of /media folder

Answer (score 16):

In windows explorer, navigate to `e:/username/folder1/folder2/`,

type `bash` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the address bar, a `bash` window with path in `e:/username/folder1/folder2/` will appear.

This also work with command `cmd`.

[Reference](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/use-the-explorer-address-bar-as-a-run-box-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 12):

A utility called `wslpath` that is shipped with both WSL and WSL2 can translate Windows paths to WSL paths (or translate WSL paths to Windows paths). For example, the command `wslpath 'E:\username\folder1\folder2'` gives you the path in WSL `/mnt/e/username/folder1/folder2`.

By using the `wslpath` utility, I define the following function in my `~/.bashrc` to quickly `cd` to Windows paths.

`` cdw() { local d=`wslpath "$1"`; cd "$d"; } ``

With this user defined function, I can easily `cd` to `E:\username\folder1\folder2` by simply typing

`cdw 'E:\username\folder1\folder2'`

Remember to wrap the Windows path by single quotes if it contains backslashes.

---

**Changelog:** June 11, 2022 - Improve the `cdw` function to make it work for space-containing paths such as `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: Wow.  Usually when I see a question this old with 5 answers already, and a new user comes along with an answer, it's pretty bad.  But not this time!  Bravo for providing an answer that actually contributes something useful that was not covered in the others!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that. I used <kbd>shift</kbd> + right click to get "Open Powershell here" whichever directory you want to bash and run 'bash' command, then run as usual enjoy. This is same as using Ubuntu bash as it uses same Python packages in the Windows Powershell after using 'bash' command.

**Note:** On windows 10 latest update maybe April 2018 with WSL and developers mode enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this :
`cd E:/username/folder1/folder2/`
and then run
`python python.py`. It always works in my case on Windows machine running bash.

Answer (score 1):

with this little script you can execute every command from the directory your Powershell is currently in. It only works if the drive is already mounted to /mnt/ in the subsystem. It doesn't work with network resources.

```
function tux {$dl = (pwd).Path | wsl eval "cut -c 1 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'"; $wd = (pwd).Path | wsl eval "cut -d : -f 2 | tr '\\' '/' 2> /dev/null" ; wsl eval "cd '/mnt/$dl$wd' && eval '$args'"}
```

after you have executed it, you can use it like this:

```
tux vim test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To change directory from wsl to windows file system:

```bash
cd /mnt/c/
```

To change directory from windows (PowerShell) to wsl file system:

```
cd Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  The information on `cd /mnt/c` was already covered in two other answers, including the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/831383/1165986) from six years ago.  The additional information would probably be more suitable on another question, since it doesn't answer this particular question.  But also note that it will *only* work on Windows 11.  It will not work on Windows 10.