# How do I access files on Desktop from Ubuntu (WSL)?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I opened the Ubuntu app after installing it from the Microsoft Store. I created a username and password for the system, but I cannot access the files on my computer. How do I do that? I have command prompt for Windows 10, but I want to use the commands found in Linux.

Comment: Possibly related: [Can I change directory to a Windows drive in Ubuntu Bash on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831361/can-i-change-directory-to-a-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-bash-on-wsl)