# How can a lbuntu.iso file be verified on a windows 10 computer?

Tags: directory, home-directory

How can I verify a lubuntu download on Windows 10 computer? Ubuntu shell was installed and runs, but does not see the same directory where the lubuntu.iso file is located. How can sha256sum be run against a file on a Windows 10 computer?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Can I change directory to a Windows drive in Ubuntu Bash on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831361/can-i-change-directory-to-a-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-bash-on-wsl)

Comment: Install WSL on your Windows 10 system, and then use the wsl inbuilt sha256sum tool from within WSL?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it seems you'll have to download or write a program.

I've used quickhash in the past.
It's easy to use, opensource, has been around for years, and it's still maintained.

- https://github.com/tedsmith/quickhash
- https://www.quickhash-gui.org/

I used the GUI - it's drag and drop.