# How to get to the Windows Desktop in WSL?

Tags: command-line, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to work in desktop directory from Ubuntu terminal in Windows 10,but I'm unable to open Desktop directory from terminal.

[image: Ubuntu terminal]

My Ubuntu is installed on the C: Drive but as i mentioned i want to work in the desktop directory. How can I do this?

[image: Directories]

Comment: you should find your windows disks under /mnt or /media

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change directory to a Windows drive in Ubuntu Bash on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831361/can-i-change-directory-to-a-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-bash-on-wsl). Please search/research before asking. When asking, share your research. This saves everyone time and makes it easier to add details when asking.  Also, please don't submit screenshots of a terminal- it's difficult to read and impossible for us to select or work with the information. Instead copy/paste and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: from /mnt directory i can accessc or drive but i want  Desktop directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try at

```
/mnt/c/Users/yourUsername/Desktop
```

where `yourUsername` is your Windows user name

Comment: I can confirm that this is also working for WSL2 on windows 8